# How to install play! framework modules?

Tags: module, playframework, installation, yaml

I'm trying to install this [pagination module](https://github.com/lmcalpin/Play--Paginate) for my Play! application, but can't get it to work. I've extracted the zip file inside /play/modules/paginate-head/ and I an example here on SO, to change my dependencies.yml file into:

```
# Application dependencies

require:
    - play
    - pagination -> paginate-head

repositories:
    - My modules:
        type:       local
        artifact:   ${application.path}/../[module]
        contains:
            - paginate-head
```

But I still don't think the module is being loaded. I'm assuming it's documentation should appear on `http://localhost:9000/@documentation/home` or are there other ways to see if a module was loaded? It's not telling me anything in the console neither.

Any ideas how to get this installed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to extract a zip file, just running the command

> play install paginate-head

should work fine. But unzipping will also work. You also don't need that "repositories" section in your dependencies.yml file. Play! knows where to find modules.

The real issue is that your require should look like this:

```
require:
    - play
    - play -> paginate head
```

Notice play to the left of the '->' which signifies that it's a module. Also no dash between 'paginate' and 'head'. That's because 'paginate' is the module name and 'head' is the version and these should be separated by a space.

Also, for modules that are hosted in the main Play! modules repo, you don't even have to install them. You can just add the require above and start Play! and it will install it automatically. Though it will install under the applications modules directory, not the play modules directory.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That did help, thank you. Any idea how I can check if it was actually installed? The `play install paginate-head` command seemed to work, but the documentation was not added to the rest of the framework, so I'm not sure if it's installed now or not.

Comment: When you start your app it should print a line to the console that has "Module paginate is available" in it.

Comment: It's not saying that for some reason, but the zip file was actually extracted and removed, and the paginate-head directory has been created inside modules

Comment: If it extracted it and put it in the modules directory, seems like it should be available. I'm not sure why you don't see that message.

Comment: I installed it again, and it say I should add this line to dependencies `- play -> paginate head`, so it's installed in my main play directory. But that's not working neither

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. It's hard to tell without seeing it.

Comment: I found the problem. It seems that there's a difference between using a tab and using four space characters before the `-` If you can, edit your post and mention this, in case anyone runs on the same problem. I found it by executing `play dependencies` in console.